# What is the exact translation of this sentence?

Tags: grammar, translation, katakana

There is this sentence in my textbook that I don't quite understand the structure of:
スイスのクレーマーさんですか、ドイツのクレーマーさんですか．
So if I understood it correctly it's asking if that person is from Switzerland or from Germany but can you just connect those 2 things with a comma? The whole sentence sounds weird to me. Also, is there another and maybe better way of saying this question?

Answer (score 1):

The question literally translates as:

```
Is it (the) swiss Mr. Kremer or is it the german Mr. Kremer?
```

(It could could be also Mrs. instead of Mr. depending on context.)
You might be confused by the literal translation since it implies that there are 2 Mr. Kremers, one from Germany and one from Switzerland.

But despite this somewhat strange phrasing (which might be, however, clear from context) the

```
...ですか、...ですか。
```

is a perfectly valid way to ask a 2-way question:
see e.g.:

[first example here](https://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/ka-dou-ka.html),

[example 5 here](http://www.japaneseammo.com/all-about-%E3%81%8B-its-not-only-a-question-marker/)

[Choice Questions (no. 3)](https://crunchynihongo.com/particle-ka-and-questions/)